# Django CORS Handler is false but not but not rejecting API requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-signals, django-cors-headers

When I run my Django CORS framework, nothing gets filtered out. The value gets evaluated to false when I insert print statements to the handlers but it's not filtering out requests to my view endpoint. Do I need to make any changes to my view? Am I missing something that will make it reject requests that don't meet the criteria in `cors_allow_mysites`?

`handlers.py`

```
from corsheaders.signals import check_request_enabled

def cors_allow_mysites(sender, request, **kwargs):
   return ("Origin" in request.headers) and (request.headers["Origin"] == 'url.com')

check_request_enabled.connect(cors_allow_mysites)
```

`apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ApiEndpointConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api_endpoint'

def ready(self):
    # Makes sure all signal handlers are connected
    from . import handlers  # noqa
```

`__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = "api_endpoint.apps.ApiEndpointConfig"
```

Answer (score 0):

What the `check_request_enabled` signal does is determine **whether CORS headers (like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")  are added to the response or not**, it does not "filter out requests".

When your `cors_allow_mysites` function returns `True`, you should expect to see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and other CORS headers in the response, and you should it if it returns `False`.

With regards to requests being filtered or not, it all depends on whether those headers are needed or not. If you are on "http://example.com", and you are fetching data from "http://example.com", the CORS headers are not needed, so without the headers, the requests will go through just fine. It's only for cross-origin requests that these headers are needed.